# Can you make a SharePoint View that will only show items from Last Year

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view, calculated-column-formula, view

If at all possible I want to create a SharePoint View on a list that will only show items from the Previous Year. I have a view to show the current year using two calculated columns, but I am trying to accomplish the same thing for the Prior Year.

In the end I want to be able to click on the Previous Year and export to excel.  The option I know of that works is to export to excel and then in excel filter by the year.  I am just trying to make this as easy as possible for the user.  I want it to be Dynamic, so it will automatically show the entries from last year once the new year turns over.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a calculated column "*PreviousYear*" (numeric format) with the following formula:

```
=IF(YEAR([Created])=(YEAR(TODAY())-1),1,0)
```

And then specify filter on your view: *PreviousYear equals 1*

P.S.

- it could be any datetime column instead of *[Created]*
- don't forget that delimiters in formula are dependent on site regional settings

Answer (score 0):

I created a calculated field using an IF statement that classifies my data from the Submitted Field (a date column in my list).  I titled the column Age.  If it is the current year the value is Current, if it is the previous year the value is Previous, anything else is classified as "Older".

=IF(YEAR(**Submitted**)=(YEAR(TODAY())),"Current",
IF(YEAR(**Submitted**)=YEAR(TODAY())-1),"Previous",
"Older"))
**you can use this with any date column by changing **Submitted** to your column name.*

Then create a view and Filter for **Age** contains Previous (or other desired option).